# Issues with Vue installation

Tags: vue.js, webpack

I'm new to Vue, this may seem a basic question but I'm stuck with this problem:

I have installed Vue 3 using npm, according to the documentation:

> https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/installation.html#npm

I have included Vue to my `html` file, like so:

```
<script src="../node_modules/vue/dist/vue.csj.js"></script>
```

But I get this error in the console:

> vue.cjs.js:3 Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined
> at vue.cjs.js:3 (anonymous) @ vue.cjs.js:3

I have seen some similar issues and I know it has something to do with browser compatibility and webpack; like the browser does not natively recognise import/export commands but it seems like everything is installed correctly and I don't know how to solve this issue. I couldn't find anything helpful in the documentation.

**So my question is**

How do I successfully install Vue and include it in my working files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you followed that guide correctly. I would recommend you install the Vue CLI, then create your app using the cli:

`$ npm install -g @vue/cli` - install cli

`$ vue create my-app`

https://cli.vuejs.org/

However, if you don't want the CLI, I'd recommend a CDN:

`<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>`

Or you can just copy the contents of the file to your app, maybe `vue.js`
(https://unpkg.com/vue@next).

And you then on your html `<script src="vue.js"></script>`

Comment: Thank you. Actually tried that but I ended up giving up as It gives me an error: `vue command not found`. Probably it's something to do with paths tho. Anyway, I thought I could just use npm without having to install the CLI. Thank you for the clarifications.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly ,
npm install -g @vue/cli After ,
on commandline run vue ui
and create a project

Comment: Thank you. Actually tried that but I ended up giving up as It gives me an error: `vue command not found`.